# Prompt "Missing node v0.10 and/or higher and npm 1.4 or higher" while running wikipedia ios project

Tags: ios, build, npm, wikipedia

I'm trying to follow the wikipedia ios project at https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-ios-wikipedia/ and I'm having problem while running "make get-deps". I always got the prompt of "Missing node v0.10 and/or higher and npm 1.4 or higher", but I do have the node & npm installed already.

The version of node is v0.12.0 and the version of npm is 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relevant code is [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-ios-wikipedia/blob/0c9e17c1dc6c63daebf3267e6a9bf1c353fd10eb/Makefile#L76-82). The `Makefile` is essentially asking for `npm@1.4`; the message says "1.4 or higher" but really the code is only checking for `1.4` (despite `npm@2`'s existence for a few months now). Until they update that, you might be able to simply comment out the `exit 1` so that the process continues.